# Suddenly my VPS server is being flooded?

Tags: linux, security, apache-2.2

I have nowhere else to ask, I just noticed that my server isn't responding, or it takes a lot of time. I have a classifieds website which uses mysql and php.

I use PUTTY and wrote `top` to see whats bothering the server. There is something EATING up CPU, and it is some java application. No idea what it is. Anybody know what I should do? Please guide me?

Have I been hacked?

EDIT: I just restarted the server from a control-panel my VPS provider offers, now the numbers are ok... What could it been?

Thanks

UPDATE.

I use SOLR, and that is the only Java because it uses Jetty as a container.

Could this be that a call was made and not cancelled and hence it caused a loop somehow.
Anybody who used solr experienced this?

Comment: You really should contact your hosting provider.

Comment: This question more from http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you should provide the app that was eating up the CPU and the parameters supplied. Use `ps aux` to get a detailed list of processes

Comment: @Camran: You do have somewhere else to ask, ServerFault. @Andrew: Except for a few, rare, full-service providers, VPS administration is the responsibility of the customer, not the provider, just as it would be with a rented or co-located server. On a VPS, the customer is root.

Comment: Well then check my update for a relevant question

Answer (score 2):

Is might be caused by `solr`

possible causes

1. too many write to the collection causing lots of fragmented files
2. solr query not optimized

for cause 1 : optimize that collection will help

cause 2 : review your query (what else?)

for this problem, you don't have to restart your server,
restart jetty and apache should be sufficient